Choice of a scaling factor to flip an inequality
Let ${0 < \delta < 1/2}$. For any ${n} \in {\bf N}$, let ${j}$ be the index such that ${n_{j,\delta} \leq n < n_{j+1,\delta}}$, where ${n_{j,\delta} := \lfloor (1+\delta)^j \rfloor}$. Then for sufficiently large ${n}$, we have
$\displaystyle  (1+2\delta) n_{j,\delta} \geq n \geq \frac{1}{1+2\delta} n_{j+1,\delta}$
Question:: I can't immediately see how the inequality follows except from a crude intuition that by definition, for large enough $n$ (and hence $j$), $n_{j, \delta} \approx (1 + \delta)^j$ in the sense that the relative error $\displaystyle |\frac{(1 + \delta)^j - n_{j, \delta}}{(1 + \delta)^j}|$ can be made arbitrarily small. Hence one has $(1 + 2\delta)n_{j, \delta} \geq n_{j+1, \delta}$ and $\frac{1}{1 + 2\delta} n_{j+1, \delta} \leq n_{j, \delta}$, with the factor $2$ serving as a safety margin here.

Is $n$ an integer, or some arbitrary real?

@Semiclassical: $n$ is assumed to be a natural number here.

From the definition of the floor function, we have
$$
(1+\delta)^j-1<n_{j,\delta}\le n<n_{j+1,\delta}\le(1+\delta)^{j+1}\ .\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
If $\ n>\frac{(1+2\delta)(1+\delta)}{\delta}\ ,$ then the rightmost pair of the above inequalities gives
\begin{align}
(1+\delta)^j&=\frac{(1+\delta)^
{j+1}}{1+\delta}\\
&>\frac{n}{1+\delta}\\
&>\frac{1+2\delta}{\delta}\ ,\tag{2}\label{e2}
\end{align}
and then the leftmost pair and the rightmost of the inequalities \eqref{e1} give
\begin{align}
(1+2\delta)n&>(1+2\delta)\big((1+\delta)^j-1\big)\\
&=(1+\delta)^{j+1}+\delta(1+\delta)^j-(1+2\delta)\\
&=(1+\delta)^{j+1}+\delta\left((1+\delta)^j-\frac{1+2\delta}{\delta}\right)\\
&>(1+\delta)^{j+1}\hspace{3em}\text{from \eqref{e2}}\\
&\ge n_{j+1,\delta}
\end{align}
from which it follows that $\ n>\frac{n_{j+1,\delta}}{1+2\delta}\ .$ Likewise, it follows from the inequalities \eqref{e1} and \eqref{e2} that
\begin{align}
(1+2\delta)n_{j,\delta}&>(1+2\delta)\big((1+\delta)^j-1\big)\\
&=(1+\delta)^{j+1}+\delta(1+\delta)^j-(1+2\delta)\\
&=(1+\delta)^{j+1}+\delta\left((1+\delta)^j-\frac{1+2\delta}{\delta}\right)\\
&>(1+\delta)^{j+1}\\
&>n\ .
\end{align}

It turns out by definition one simply has (for sufficiently large $j$) that $\displaystyle (1 + 2\delta)n_{j, \delta} \geq (1 + 2\delta)((1 + \delta)^j - 1) = (1 + \delta)^{j+1} + \delta(1 + \delta)^j - (1 + 2\delta) \geq n_{j+1, \delta}$, and thus $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1 + 2\delta} n_{j+1, \delta} \leq n_{j, \delta}$. But anyway thanks for your response.
